# How to change boot option and set the USB as first boot option

Tags: usb-boot

I am configuring my ASUS A53SC laptop with a dual-boot dystem. I already have Windows intalled and I want to install Linux from my USB stick. Booting from USB is not configured, and I can't add a new boot option in the BIOS.

My Laptop is running Windows 7 64-bit. I cant post an image of my BIOS boot menu, but it is like this.

```
BOOT CONFIGURATION

UEFI Boot ........................................... [DISABLE]
PXE ROM.............................................. [DISABLE]

Boot Option Priorities

Boot Option #1 ...................................... [P0:Hitachi HTS547..]
Boot Option #2 ...................................... [P1:MATSHITADVD-RA..]


Hard Drive BBS Priorities

CD/DVD ROM DRIVE BBS Priorities

Delete Boot Option
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select Hard Drive BBS Priorities and you should see your usb storage device there. Then drag it to the top.

Answer (score 0):

On my computer (hp)

esc to interrupt boot process

F10 to go to BIOS settings

System info

Go left until

BOOT OPTIONS

> Device order
>
> > Press F6 to raise F5 to lower F1 to disable F10 to save and reboot arrow keys to move

arrow down to usb

F6 F6 F6 F10

Answer (score 0):

Your system type is UEFI. It means your bootable USB must contain the EFI files in the directory /EFI/BOOT folder In order to be recognized by your system at boot up.
Without those files your system will not recognize bootable USB and simply proceed to normal windows startup. Look in your disk image if it already contains these files and folder.

Visit my question with the same problem and how I managed to make it recognized: [USB not booting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/312965/192349). I created a folder in my bootable USB as /EFI/BOOT. Then I downloaded BOOTX64.efi, Grubx64.efi, MokManager.efi and grub.cfg and copied to that folder.

I'm dual booting kali-linux so the files I copied might vary according to linux OS but I'm sure .efi files are still required. These files can also be same for all linux OS as they are just only boot files.